# Is std::map exception safe with custom comparator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, exception-safety

What `std::map` will do if custom comparator throw an exception during rebalancing? Apparently, it should remember all the previous turns and return everything to its original state. Is it true?

Comment: This was featured in a talk at CPPCON.  Can't find it now but I'll try to find it when I get home later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [associative.reqmts.except]:

> For associative containers, no `clear()` function throws an exception. `erase(k)` does not throw an exception unless that exception is thrown by the container’s `Compare` object (if any).
>
> For associative containers, if an exception is thrown by any operation from within an `insert` or `emplace` function inserting a single element, the insertion has no effect.
>
> For associative containers, no `swap` function throws an exception unless that exception is thrown by the swap of the container’s `Compare` object (if any).

So you're basically right (in the case of single element insertions), but it doesn't mean the container must "remember all the previous turns" in order to "return everything to its original state". Assuming that associative containers are implemented using a self-balancing binary search tree (I'm not sure if there are any other possibilities) comparisons are only done in order to walk down the tree to find the location at which the new node must be inserted. If a comparison exits via an exception during this process, the tree hasn't been modified yet, so all the container has to do is deallocate memory it has allocated for the new element at this point (if any). The rebalancing step that follows cannot generate an exception, because it merely involves performing a bunch of tree rotations and updating internal bookkeeping data such as whether nodes are red or black.

Comment: The quoted text only says that there's no effect for an insertion if an exception is thrown. It doesn't say what state the container is in if `erase(k)` throws an exception. Was the key removed or not?

Comment: @Kevin Well, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to say. But going by the same logic, it seems impossible for the element to be removed if an exception occurs, because the container can't find the node.